# How do I know if text contains URL links (UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have some text which might or might not contain web URLs, phone numbers, email links etc. which **UIWebView automatically detects** as hotspots.

**Question:** I want to show this text in UIWebView ONLY when there are one or more hotspots, but as plain text if it doesn't. So how can I detect this in code?

**Additional Info:** JavaScript code below tells how many <a href="...">...</a> links there are. This does NOT count how many other "link" items there are. For example "Link to www.yle.fi" contains one link according to UIWebView, but zero according to JavaScript:

```
NSString *s = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                @"document.links.length"];
```

Still no answer to the question how to ask UIWebView how many links it has found...

Answer (score 0):

You can use several regular expressions and check if the text matches those of URL/phone number/email addresses.

However, if your intention is simply let the user open a link, the `UITextView` is suffice.

Check the [`dataDetectorTypes` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898-CH3-SW20).

Comment: Sorry, not really answering my question... To use regular expressions I would need to know how UIWebView internal regex works. Not better, not worse, but in same way. Mission impossible.

Comment: UITextView uses same font and color for all text. Want to hilight hotspots for user, so UIWebView + custom CSS was the way to go. Just need to know when there is need to use it == are there any links. Can't believe it cannot be done! Hmm...

Comment: @JOM: (1) No need to use the internal regex! RegexKitLite is enough. (2) You need to *turn off* editable to get http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/images/qa1495_Result.png.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts, really do, but trying to guess what random release of internal webkit branch detects as a link really is mission impossible. Have experience of 3 diff web engines R&D over about 10 years and there is NO WAY trying to make a correct guess. Got to get answer from webkit some way...